# not assignable to android.app.application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have upgraded the build/gradle/library versions in my Android app project, and am now getting this error in my AndroidManifest.xml file. Can anyone explain what I need to do to resolve this?:

`'com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.PCPhotoUploadApp' is not assignable to 'android.app.Application'`

I have tried:
- Cleaning Project
- Rebuilding
- invalidate Cache/Restart
- Resync Gradle

Here are my project files....

AndroidManifest.xml (the error is on line 22 - android:name=...)"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2"
    android:versionCode="2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
        android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />

    <application
        android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.PCPhotoUploadApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.util.NetworkConnectionActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.HeadersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_headers" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.ShowPreferences"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_show_preferences" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.ServerDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_server_details" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.SourceFolders"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_source_folders" />

        <service android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.UploadService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.NetworkListener"
            android:label="NetworkListener" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.CameraListener"
            android:label="CameraListener" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="10000" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
                <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.PowerConnectionListener" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.SetSSID"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_set_ssid" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.UploadWidget"
            android:icon="@drawable/upload_widget"
            android:label="Upload Now" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/upload_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.FirstLaunch"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_first_launch" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.HelpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.InitialUploadActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_initial_upload" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.BrowseSharesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_browse_shares" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.EmailDebugLogActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_email_debug_log" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.UploadSelectedActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_upload_selected" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.ActivityLogActivity"
            android:label="Activity Log" >
        </activity>
        <!--android:name="com.projects.realestatefinder.pcphotoupload2"-->
        <service
            android:name="com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2.util.NetworkSchedulerService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ioxis.ian.pcphotoupload2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 68
        versionName "3.24"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17'
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/logback-android-1.1.1-3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your App class also ?

Comment: I don't have a custom App class

Comment: Sorry...my mistake...I do have an App class but it extends MultiDexApplication, and I've just noticed that symbol MultiDexApplication can't be resolved